# Array expr creation using the C++ API

Tags: c++, z3

To create an array by the z3 c++ api, I did some search on the internet. The best approach I can find is:

```
context c;
sort I = c.int_sort();
sort A = c.array_sort(I, I);
expr a1 = to_expr(c, mk_var(c, "a1", A)); //this is wrapper to use the C api in my C++ code
expr b1 = store(a1, 3, 4); //then I can apply to a1 the store and select functions provided in the C++ api.
```

My question is this: is there an alternative way to create an array a1, without using C api? Does the C++ api provide a function to create a1 from A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method

```
expr constant(char const * name, sort const & s);
```

It can be used to create constants (aka variables) of the given sort. Here is an example:

```
expr a1 = c.constant("a1", A);
```